# How to use promise all on an indeterminate array

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, puppeteer

I am trying to write a generic function to fill out forms using puppeteer. In a non generic version I do something like this:

```
function fillSpecificForm(values) {

  return Promise.all([
    page.$eval('#selector1', (el, values) => el.value = values[0], values),
    page.$eval('#selector2', (el, values) => el.value = values[1], values),
    page.$eval('#selector3', (el, values) => el.value = values[2], values),
  ])

}
```

I expect a generic version would look something like this.

```
function fillAnyForm(selectors, values) {

  if(!isArray(selectors)) throw 'Parameter "selectors" must be an array'
  if(!isArray(values)) throw 'Parameter "values" must be an array'

  nPromises = Math.min(selectors.length, values.length)
  promises = []

  for(let i = 0; i < nPromises; i++) {
      promises.push(new Promise(/* This is the part I don't get */))
  }

  return Promise.all(promises);

}
```

And I can't wrap my head around generating abstract promises. So help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `page.$eval(selectors[i], (el, values) => el.value = values[i], values)` not new Promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `new Promise()`, just use the return value from `page.$eval()` the same way you do in the non-generic version.

```
for(let i = 0; i < nPromises; i++) {
    promises.push(page.$eval(selectors[i], (el, value) => el.value = value, values[i]))
}
```